# Pull data from sub object within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here but I'm getting "undefined" back in my console.
Hopefully you can see in the snippet I am passing in some JSON data. This effectively 2 stores worth of data and against each store there are a few transactions. I can pull back the top level data but I'm struggling to pull back data from the transaction line level.

Its whenever I try to reference something from within my transaction lines. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I'm referencing that part of my array?

Many thanks

```js
///Dummy JSON Data Stringified and put in the top /////////

const inputData= "[{\r\n\t\t\"transaction\": 1,\r\n\t\t\"store\": 1,\r\n\t\t\"transactionLines\": [{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 3,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 25\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 2,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 50\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 100\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t]\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t\"transaction\": 2,\r\n\t\t\"store\": 2,\r\n\t\t\"transactionLines\": [{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 2,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 50\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 100\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t]\r\n\t}\r\n]"


const input = JSON.parse(inputData);

var  total = 0;

//////   First "For Loop" goes through input data  /////
//////   and lists transactions  ///////////////////////

for(let i=0;i<input.length;i++){
console.log(input[i].transaction);

/////////   2nd "For Loop" is inside the transaction loop.  ////////
/////////   This goes through transaction data from the above loop /
/////////    and lists transactions  ///////////////////////////////

    for(let j=0;j<input[i].transactionLines.length;j++){

/////////   Increase the total by adding the line value to the /////
/////////   existing total  ////////////////////////////////////////

total = total+input[i].lineValue
console.log(input[i].transactionLines.lineId);
  console.log("Transaction ID = "+input[i].transaction+" loop x "+j+": New Total = "+input[i].transactionLines.transactionId);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>
Sample Json Data Shown Below
</h1>
<h2>
Check console for outputs
</h2>
</div>

<xmp>
  
  [{
    "transaction": 1,
    "store": 1,
    "transactionLines": [{
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 3,
            "lineValue": 25
        },

        {
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 2,
            "lineValue": 50
        },
        {
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 1,
            "lineValue": 100
        }
    ]
},
{
    "transaction": 2,
    "store": 2,
    "transactionLines": [{
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 2,
            "lineValue": 50
        },
        {
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 1,
            "lineValue": 100
        }
    ]
}
]
</xmp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `j` variable

```js
///Dummy JSON Data Stringified and put in the top /////////

const inputData = "[{\r\n\t\t\"transaction\": 1,\r\n\t\t\"store\": 1,\r\n\t\t\"transactionLines\": [{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 3,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 25\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 2,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 50\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 100\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t]\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t\"transaction\": 2,\r\n\t\t\"store\": 2,\r\n\t\t\"transactionLines\": [{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 2,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 50\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 100\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t]\r\n\t}\r\n]"


const input = JSON.parse(inputData);

var total = 0;

//////   First "For Loop" goes through input data  /////
//////   and lists transactions  ///////////////////////

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  console.log(input[i].transaction);

  /////////   2nd "For Loop" is inside the transaction loop.  ////////
  /////////   This goes through transaction data from the above loop /
  /////////    and lists transactions  ///////////////////////////////

  for (let j = 0; j < input[i].transactionLines.length; j++) {

    /////////   Increase the total by adding the line value to the /////
    /////////   existing total  ////////////////////////////////////////

    total = total + input[i].lineValue
    console.log(input[i].transactionLines[j].lineId);
    console.log("Transaction ID = " + input[i].transaction + " loop x " + j + ": New Total = " + input[i].transactionLines[j].transactionId);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    Sample Json Data Shown Below
  </h1>
  <h2>
    Check console for outputs
  </h2>
</div>

<xmp>

  [{ "transaction": 1, "store": 1, "transactionLines": [{ "transactionId": 1, "lineId": 3, "lineValue": 25 }, { "transactionId": 1, "lineId": 2, "lineValue": 50 }, { "transactionId": 1, "lineId": 1, "lineValue": 100 } ] }, { "transaction": 2, "store": 2,
  "transactionLines": [{ "transactionId": 1, "lineId": 2, "lineValue": 50 }, { "transactionId": 1, "lineId": 1, "lineValue": 100 } ] } ]
</xmp>
```